# Node.js - Read and Write thousands/millions of JSON files in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I need to process a huge amount of files in a most efficient and fast way.

Read -> Process -> Write (save to same place).

My problem is that my implementation is slow, at least I think so. It took me half a night or so to process 600000 files.

I did it in a synchronous manner on purpose, if this can be done better asynchronously - I'm open to solutions, I just didn't think that processing a lot of files which weigh only 1-3kb will take that long.

Files have simple JSON data and each file is about 1-3kb size like I already said.

Those files lie in separate folders each containing 300 files. I split them up in order to make it more efficient and usable.

So we have ~ 2000 folders each having 300 files (1-3kb size).

Take a look at my code and gimme your thoughts. Thanks!

```
function test() {

    /**
     * Get list of folders and loop through
     */
    const folderList = fs.readdirSync(`../db`)

    for (const folder of folderList) {

        /**
         * Get list of files for each folder and loop through
         */
        const fileList = fs.readdirSync(`../db/${ folder }`)

        for (const filePath of fileList) {

            /**
             * try/catch block to handle JSON.parse errors
             */
            try {

                /**
                 * Read file
                 */
                const file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`../db/${ folder }/${ filePath }`))

                /**
                 * Process file
                 */
                processFile(file)

                /**
                 * Write file
                 */
                fs.writeFileSync(`../db/${ folder }/${ filePath }`, JSON.stringify(file), 'utf8')

            } catch (err) {

                console.log(err)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect this to run rather quickly, in reality this takes a while.

Comment: All operations appear synchronous. Is this on purpose?

Comment: Couple of thoughts: You're using synchronous/blocking calls to read and write files; you could see some improvement by using async/non-blocking calls here; but there will be a sweet-spot on the number of parallel operations; e.g. maybe running 10 iterations simultaneously will help, but 10,000 may have adverse effect, so you'll have to try: https://github.com/feross/run-parallel-limit. Also, your `processFile` is opaque. What's happening in there? If that's a CPU intensive task, you can run it in a Worker Thread. https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

Comment: This question may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since you're looking for improvements on working code :)

Comment: I also noticed, that if I run a script once, if I stop it and run again it will quickly loop throught the already processed files (though we process them and not skip) and when it comes to the number we stop at - it starts to slow down again.

Comment: @Boaz yes, but I'm open to try async manner. I just didn't think that processing little JSON object could take that long.

Comment: @ArashMotamedi Thanks, could you rewrite my sample so that it will asynchronously process 10-20-30-etc files at a time and not more? processFile isn't CPU intensive task by any means. It just grabs 30 random items from a 60k array of words and appends this to the object we read.

Comment: @frobinsonj Ty, I will try!

Comment: @yegorchik At scale, even very simple tasks can take a very long time if not handled asynchronously. For example, let's assume the read and write operations alone take just 50ms each. Handled synchronously, it would take about 8 hours (`600000*0.05/60/60`) to complete.

Comment: @Boaz you are right. I just tried out my code and commented out some stuff, and came to conclusion that #1 thing which makes the code slow is the fs.readFileSync. If I comment it out, I process the files rather quickly. If I read each file, it really takes a while. So your thought is to process not a file by file, but rather a chunk by chunk, right? Like 10 or 100 files at a time asynchronously. What is the best way to perform this? I tried out async code but did it quickly and didn't bother about memory leak so it throwed me an error (too many files open).

Comment: Take a look at [graceful-fs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs)

Comment: @frobinsonj can you kindly check my answer?

Comment: @Boaz as well as you

Comment: @ArashMotamedi and you mate

Answer (score 0):

Yo guys, so I've came up with this solution as a test, can you check it out and let me know if it's a good implementation? This took like 10-15 minutes to process 600k files instead of hours. Each 'folder' has 300 files in it, so we always wait for 300 promises to complete. I do it so because the files are small (1-3kb, one object, nothing fancy). Could this be done better, could this be done in a minute for example? :)

```
async function test() {

    const folderList = fs.readdirSync(`../db`)

    for (const folder of folderList) {

        console.log(folder)

        const fileList = fs.readdirSync(`../db/${ folder }`)

        let promises = []

        for (const fileName of fileList) {
            promises.push(processFile(site, folder, fileName))
        }

        await Promise.all(promises)

    }
}

async function processFile(folder, fileName) {

    const path = `../db/${ folder }/${ fileName }`

    const file = await readFile(path)

    if (file){
        //do something and write
        await writeFile(path)
    }

}

function readFile(path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {

        fs.readFile(path, function (err, raw) {

            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                resolve()
                return
            }

            try {
                const file = JSON.parse(raw)
                resolve(file)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
                resolve()
            }

        })

    })
}

function writeFile(path, object) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {

        fs.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(object), function (err) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err)

            resolve()
        })

    })
}
```

Comment: yes.this can be done better.10-15 minutes is a huge time.Instead of waiting for 300 promises to complete just register callback for each promise and process each one individually.That will be much faster.I think it will hardly take 2 minutes

Comment: @Sanjay take a look at my new answer please.

Answer (score 0):

So, after playing around with some stuff, I've came to something like this:

```
const PromisePool = require('es6-promise-pool')

const list = require('./list.json')

let n = 0

let pool = new PromisePool(promiseProducer, 11)

pool.start()
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Complete')
    })

function promiseProducer(){

    console.log(n)

    if (n < list.length)
        return processFile(list[++n])
    else
        return null
}
```

This ran rather fast. Though, I still have some questions.

1. Can anyone write their own implementation of concurrency limit? Without libraries etc
2. Like before, if I run the script and wait for 20k (for example) files to be processed, if I stop the script and rerun, it will come to 20k (where we stop) REALLY quick and then it will slow down. What is the reason?

Comment: without libraries,node.js can handle thousands of concurrent requests as you can see in many articles on internet.Incase when you use libraries,the concurrency limit will change depending on the specific library like most libraries that are used to generate html-pdf have a concurrency of only 1 to avoid more load.similarly for other libraries as well,the concurrency limit might vary.Also the concurrency limit will depend on your hardware as well